# Can't get variable out of Callback function. Already defined as global. Matlab

Tags: matlab, callback, workspace

I have a serialport bytesavailable callback function.

```
function readFrame(src,~)
global data
global payloadBytes
message = read(src,payloadBytes,"uint8");
src.UserData = message;
data = message;
return
```

I read the buffer into the variable message and then save it as global variable data.
i get the variable in my workspace. Then something happens that I can't explain. I try to save this global variable in a local variable in my Mainscript. Notice: global data is defined in mainscript.

```
global data;
global payloadBytes;
msg=[];
frameCount = 1;
numFrames = 10;
messageByte = zeros(numFrames,payloadBytes)

while(app)
        
       %wait till callback triggered and serial data read 
       while isempty(msg)
           %save global variable data in local variable msg
           msg = data;
           disp("wait for data")
       end
      
       %save msg in an expanding 2D Variable messagebyte 
       messageByte(frameCount,:) = msg;
        %empty msg variable 
        msg =[]
        frameCount = frameCount +1
  
        %stop when 10 frames are caught
        if frameCount == 11

        app = 0;
        end
    
end
```

Problem is processedData is always empty. So when i want to make a 2D Matrice to save different data like this:

```
processedData(frameCount,:) = data;
```

I get an exception: indices doesn't match. Thats no wonder.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to say `global data` in every context where you want to use the global value. On the other hand, there is almost always a better design that does not use globals. Globals make code harder to understand.

Comment: If you need more help than this, please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly. It is unclear exactly what is going on where you use `data`.

Comment: Value is global in every context. I will edit my post with more code

Comment: Ok, so what happens? The `while isempty(msg)` loop never exits? Or it does exit but then `messageByte(frameCount,:) = msg` errors out because `msg` has the wrong number of elements? (Your code and text don’t 100% match up.)

Comment: Have a look at this example on FileExchange: [serialDataStream](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31958-serialdatastream)

Comment: @CrisLuengo msg never exits. msg ist always empty inside my Mainscript. But if i stop the script msg has the serialdata . So callback works. msg gets the data of serialport. But in the Mainscript msg is still empty. Sorry for confussion and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB is single-threaded. Stuff doesn’t run in parallel unless you explicitly use the Parallel Processing Toolbox. So for your callback to write to `data`, your main loop must give the callback a chance to execute. Add a `pause` to your loop, this will allow callbacks to execute, as well as timer objects.

```matlab
       while isempty(msg)
           pause(0.1) % find a suitable pause length here
           %save global variable data in local variable msg
           msg = data;
           disp("wait for data")
       end
```

The pause doesn’t need to be long, but make it as long as you can tolerate, since that will make your wait less processor intensive.

Comment: I recommend using [`drawnow()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) instead of `pause()` for this situation. `drawnow()` is designed explicitly for this use case (allow callbacks, refresh figures), and the pause() function has a history of creating memory leaks.

Comment: @mhopeng Do you have a reference for the memory leaks? I've never encountered them or heard about them. In the past, `drawnow` would often not work (maybe it's fixed now?), but a `pause` has always worked well. In any case, I made the argument in the answer than pausing is a good thing: not checking too often for data to have arrived reduces the amount of energy wasted.

Comment: Thank you very much !  It works ! Both solutions! Didn't get the right answer even in the Mathworks forum. I have to modify my code a little bit.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sure, for example see [this thread](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/209757-has-matlab-2013b-and-newer-fixed-the-memory-leak-issues-in-pause-and-delete) and the links in it. Maybe this has been fixed in recent versions, I don't know.